# How to apply Jquery to textbox, CssClass instead of ID in Jquery,Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using one JQuery plugin which is giving me Calendar with Time selection on click of that textbox this plugin very flexible to use.

below is the code which I am referring to use this plugin.

```
   <link href="DateTimePicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="DateTimePicker/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="DateTimePicker/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
                mask: '9999/19/39 29:59'
            });

        });
    </script>
<h3>Mask DateTimePicker</h3>

<input type="text" value="" id="datetimepicker_mask"/><br><br>
```

***Above code works fine for me for single Textbox.***

but I have to use this plugin for more then one textbox so this I can use only if this plugin is taking by Class instaed of Id.

so I am not getting what change I have to do in the Jquery to achieve the task.
there are so many Jquery & Css which is dependent on this.

Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: Do you mean `$('.className').datetimepicker...)` ?

Comment: Change your JS to `$('.datetimepicker_mask')` and your HTML to `<input type="text" value="" class="datetimepicker_mask"/>` then you can have multiple inputs with the same class (note: ofc you can keep the ID attribute, too - but a second input would need its own unique id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's selectors are very similar to CSS selectors. So you can use `.class` to select by class.

In your example you would change your selector to

```
$('.datetimepicker_mask')
```

And use a class on your `input` instead of id

```
<input type="text" value="" class="datetimepicker_mask"/>
```